# OpecnCV's filter2D output image

Tags: opencv

I use OpenCV's filter2D API for filtering the center image (41 x 41) with black colour kernel (size 11 x 11). The filter output image is the first with 2 dots. I am expecting the image like the last image with four dots. What could be wrong? My program is as follow.

```
int imfilter(Mat &src, Mat &ker, Mat &dest)
{      
     Point anchor( -1,-1);    
     float delta = 0.0;    
     cv::filter2D(src, dest, CV_32FC1, ker, anchor, delta, BORDER_REPLICATE);    
     return 1;
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'black color kernel'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the black regions where you want to be 2 more dots  are in fact negative valued pixels, try taking absolute value of dest by calling

```
dest = cv::abs(dest);
```